# magento login page loads with a white background

Tags: php, magento-1.8

I use magento 1.8.1 and I just moved my localhost site to a new server and imported my database using phpmyadmin and deleted the contents inside var/cache & var/session folders but when I try to access my backend the login page is loading in left top corner with a white background.

I viewed the page source of my login page and found that the url was missing some parameter (/) to discuss in detail instead of pointing to 
`"127.0.0.1/july/js/prototype/prototype.js";`      it points as follows 
`"127.0.0.1/julyjs/prototype/prototype.js";`       note that / is missing between july and js.

But my css and js for frontend is rendered correctly i do know why this weird problem occurs.

However I can access to my backend and my localhost login page is still loading fine but the magento login page in my new server is not loading fine. what should i do to make my login page render correctly.

I don't know what went wrong. Please help me out to solve this issue.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run these queries on your database;

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET `store_id` = '0' WHERE `store_id` = 2 LIMIT 1 ;
UPDATE `core_website` SET `website_id` = '0' WHERE `website_id` = 2 LIMIT 1 ;
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET `group_id` = '0' WHERE `group_id` = 2 LIMIT 1 ;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

also check these values and make sure to add `"/"` end of the url as per the magento norms

```
open table core_config_data
correct the value for web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url 
set the value to 0 for both dev/js/merge_files and dev/css/merge_css_files
```

Comment: sorry for late reply I found out the reason why do my login page is not rendered properly i viewed the page source of my login page and found that the url was missing some parameter (/) to discuss in detail instead of pointing to "http://127.0.0.1/july/js/prototype/prototype.js"  it points as follows                   "http://127.0.0.1/julyjs/prototype/prototype.js"   note that the slash is missing before js     how could i solve this problem i dont find  dev/js/merge_files or dev/css/merge_css_files in my core_config_data table what should i do now?

Comment: As you have resolved your issue than no need to find out dev/js/merge_files and other entries.

Comment: i didn't resolve my issue i just found the reason why it is happening i don't know how to proceed further and solve this issue.Please help me.....

Comment: can you please edit your question to understand current issue?

Comment: update your web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url values and add / end of the url. Please go through my answer and check the 2nd block where I have ask to correct the values.

Comment: i dont have dev/js/merge_files and dev/css/merge_css_files paths in core_config_data table

Comment: if you don't have these fields  than leave but update the values in web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url. can you please share what values you have in these fields?

Comment: adding / at the end of url did the trick.Thank you very much you saved my day and sorry for late reply.